# Add two string arrays to one ListView column

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, listview

I am trying to write to only one column of a listView (a subitem) but I want it so I can run two arrays through it not just one array.

When I try to do that it adds it to the next column in the listView (not the one i want it to write to).

For example this adds the array to different columns, not all of them to the same one:

```
 string[] k = getBetweenAll(thepage, "<h4 style=\"padding:0 0 0 3px;\"><a href=\"", "\" target=\"_blank\">");
 string[] q = getBetweenAll(thepage, "<h4><a href=\"", "\" target=\"_blank\">");
 for (int i = 0; i < k.Length && i < listViewClickbank.Items.Count; i++)
 {

     listViewClickbank.Items[i].SubItems.Add(input + k[i]);
     listViewClickbank.Items[i].SubItems.Add(input + q[i]);
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
     string[] k = getBetweenAll(thepage, "<h4 style=\"padding:0 0 0 3px;\"><a href=\"", "\" target=\"_blank\">");
     string[] q = getBetweenAll(thepage, "<h4><a href=\"", "\" target=\"_blank\">");
     var items = listViewClickbank.Items;


     var z = new int[k.Length + q.Length]; 
     k.CopyTo(z, 0);
     q.CopyTo(z, k.Length);

     for (int i = 0; i < z.Length; i++)
     {
         Items.SubItems.Add(input + z[i]);
     }
```

Comment: I am getting "Index was outside the bounds of the array." for  listViewClickbank.Items[1].SubItems.Add(input + q[i]);

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear from your question exactly what the result is that you are looking for, but if you want both values concatenated together into one column of one row, do this:

```
listViewClickbank.Items[i].SubItems.Add(input + k[i] + q[i]);
```

Comment: I got "Index was outside the bounds of the array."

Answer (score 1):

Concatenate the two arrays before adding them to the listview.

```
var z = new string[k.Length + q.Length];
k.CopyTo(z, 0);
q.CopyTo(z, k.Length);

//TODO: Add z to the listview
```

Or you can do it without concatenation

```
 for (int i = 0; i < k.Length + q.Length; i++)
 {
     if (i < k.Length) {
         Items.SubItems.Add(input + k[i]);
     } else {
         Items.SubItems.Add(input + q[i - k.Length]);
     }
 }
```

Comment: I got "Index was outside the bounds of the array."

Comment: It should work. Note that in the second copy operation you have to pass the length of the first array (not the second).